# How to refer to instance type of an old-style constructor function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How to use old style class declarations via Functions as Type annotations

```
function Foo () {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'bar';

let x:Foo;
console.log(x.bar);
```

Unfortunately we can't write "let x:Foo" as TypeScript fails with error:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'Foo'.

I tried other way:

```
function Foo () {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'bar';

declare type FooType = typeof Foo
let x:FooType;
```

But `x` is then the function, not a instance of `Foo`. TypeScript has also `InstanceType<T>` generics, but again - just the `Foo` we can't use, as `Foo` is not the type annotation.

Any solution how to use class-functions like `Foo` with prototype as a type annotation?

**EDIT**

Sure, we can create additionaly the `IFoo` interface with all the copy-pasted properties as was suggested in answers, but this is definitly not want you want to do, when you have a lot of properties. Then also to keep the functions prototype and the interface in sync would make also not much fun. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
// Use to specify the properties on your final object
interface IFoo {
    bar: string;
}

// Class Definition
function Foo() { }; 
Foo.prototype.bar = 'bar';

// Use it
let x:IFoo = new Foo();
console.log(x.bar);
```

Comment: The problem is when `Foo` has many properties, you have to track them all separately in `IFoo` interface.  It is absolutely not convenient. Any sollution to create the interface without having to copy-past all properties?

Comment: I think that is hard, as by using `.prototype.` you are adding properties to your object dynamically. So there is no way the TS parser can predict what is going to happen at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Foo() { }
Foo.prototype.bar = 'bar'

interface Foo {
    new(): {
        bar: string
    }
}

let x: InstanceType<Foo>
```

I think the only solution is to define an Interface of `Foo`. I don't know if TypeScript can properly infer what was assigned to prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure: would you like `x` to be a *newable function*, or the result of calling one? For the former, you may need the [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) section from the handbook. For the latter, perhaps what you're really looking for is this:

```
class Foo {
    bar = 'bar'
}

declare let x: Foo;
console.log(x.bar)
```

Comment: Thanks Karol, yes, it should be a newable function. Same as `class Foo`, so that `x:Foo` where x is the `instance` of `Foo`, not the `Foo` itself.  Sure by overwriting this into `classes` or `interfaces` everything works fine.  I'm asking about this specific case where `Function` is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the old-style class in a `.js` file and enable the `allowJs` compiler option, then TypeScript will analyze assignments to properties of `this` in the body of the `Foo` constructor function as well as assignments to properties of `Foo.prototype` and come up with a return type for `new Foo()`.  That still doesn't define a `Foo` type.  To get that, you can do:

```
let dummyFoo = (false as true) && new Foo();
type Foo = typeof dummyFoo;
```

(I learned this trick from [here](http://www.johnfn.com/ts-best-line.html), though I don't know if that's where it originated.)

I don't believe there's any way to get type information for an old-style class declaration that appears in a `.ts` file.